# Eclipse: Exporting into runnable Jar. How to change the autogenerated workspace folder location?

Tags: java, eclipse, export, executable-jar, workspace

I have a Java code with main method that I exported into a runnable jar using Eclipse. The problem is, when I run this file; it generates a workspace folder. In this workspace folder, it stores the user-configuration etc. that was entered in the program. This "workspace" folder is generated in the same folder where the original .jar file is.

What I want is to somehow change the location of this folder to some other place. Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Can you let us know the steps you are doing?

Comment: Right Clicked on ProjectName>Export>Runnable Jar File. Then just set up the destination path and click 'OK'. For library handling, I selected "Extract Required libraries into generated JAR".

Comment: instead of extract required libraries into generated jar ,try package required libraries into generated jar

Comment: I did that. Did not work. It is not the problem. The problem is my runnable jar file (run.jar) is actually just a wrapper that runs an exported eclipse application. That application needs to store it's preferences. And because my run.jar is the one executing that application it creates a "workspace" folder just when I double click on it. Not before. And when I set up the preferences in that main application they are stored into that workspace that was just created.

Comment: If thats the case build a jar from command line.Then i hope it should work.

Comment: Your answer gave me a clue on how to fix it. I changed the parameters as to how I was running it so that I set the workspace to my own preferred location. Now when I export it and run it, the workspace is set to that location. Thank you very much for the help :)